# Gforge tracker are not saved using the e-mail gateway with PHP

Tags: php, email, gateway, tracker, gforge

We are using gforge and we want create new trackers just by using an intranet form and by sending an email with PHP to the gforge e-mail gateway.

I do it exactly like it is said:

I use this for the recipient:

> You can add new tracker items by
>   sending an e-mail to
>   gforge-gateway@gforge.XXX.local from
>   your user's e-mail account.

I use my (local) email address used for my gforge user account as sender. The subject looks like 'Test_tracker (tracker-32)' as it is said here

> Item Summary (tracker-17)

and all i have in the body is 'assignees:lillm' (thats a username from gforge).

PHP tells me that the mail was send succeccfully but no new tracker appears. 
Do i have to use HTML mails or text mails? Is the priority and/or the start/end date important? Or did i forgot something?

Comment: Or is there a way to debug the mail gateway? What file is called when a new message is recieved inside gforge?

Comment: OK, when i use Apple Mail to send this message everything is fine. So something must be wrong with PHP sending the mail. hmmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah damn, the problem was that i sent the email with the native php mailer. I tried to send the mail with a smtp user and now Gforge is getting the mail. It's that simple ;-)